# C++ conflicting namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am developing a `C++` project in `prj_cpp.h` which starts as

```
// prj_cpp.h
#include "lib_cpp.h"
extern "C" {
#include "lib_c.h"
}
```

Where `lib_cpp.h` and `lib_c.h` are header files of external C++ and C libraries respectively.

External C++ library `lib_cpp.h` also uses `lib_c` in the following way.

```
// lib_cpp.h
namespace SOME_WEIRD_NAMESPACE {
extern "C" {
#include "lib_c.h"
}
}
```

Because `lib_c.h` prevents double inclusion, it turns out that all objects in `lib_c.h` reside in `SOME_WEIRD_NAMESPACE` which has nothing to do with my project `prj_cpp`.

On the other hand if my header file looks like

```
// prj_cpp.h
extern "C" {
#include "lib_c.h"
}
#include "lib_cpp.h"
```

I break the external `C++` project because there is nothing under `SOME_WEIRD_NAMESPACE` because I include `lib_c.h` first.

I am not allowed to modify neither `lib_cpp.h` nor `lib_c.h`

Is there anything I can do in my `prj_cpp.h` to resolve such an issue?

I do not like very much using `SOME_WEIRD_NAMESPACE` in my project because that namespace has nothing to do with it. Moreover, the number of `lib_c.h` headers files can be large.

Comment: lib_cpp.h is broken. This is the fundamental problem, and fixing it is the right fix.

Comment: Agreed, what would be the proper fix? Prevent using lib_c.h under namespaces?

Comment: write new, non-broken versions of lib_cpp.h and lib_c.h and use them instead of the originals. The originals are unmodified, so the assignment spec is still met.

Comment: OK, how the non-broken version of lib_cpp.h should look like? Never use C header files under the namespace clause?

Comment: Header files are **not** libraries!

Comment: Of course not, but this is how people usually use libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use lib_cpp.h more than lib_c.h, replace #include lib_c.h with the following wrapper:

```
// lib_c_wrapper.h
namespace SOME_WEIRD_NAMESPACE {
extern "C" {
#include "lib_c.h"
}
}
```

If you use lib_c.h more than lib_cpp.h use the following wrapper:

```
// lib_cpp_wrapper.h
#define SOME_WEIRD_NAMESPACE YOUR_NAMESPACE
#include "lib_cpp.h"
```

This is a workaround to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Since lib_cpp.h and lib_c.h are from third parties and new versions of those libraries might provide new, different versions of those files, it will avoid future maintenance issues if you don't alter them. Also you state that your specification is that you don't alter them. So wrap them and exclusively use the wrappers in your code to resolve the issue.

The first approach that occurs to me is:

```
//wrapped_lib_c.h
#ifndef WRAPPED_LIB_C_INC_GUARD
#define  WRAPPED_LIB_C_INC_GUARD

namespace SOME_WEIRD_NAMESPACE
{
  extern "C" 
  {       
    #include "lib_c.h"
  }
}

namespace SOME_PROJECT_APPROPRIATE_NAMESPACE
{
  using SOME_WEIRD_NAMESPACE;
}

#endif
```

and

```
//wrapped_lib_cpp.h 
#ifndef WRAPPED_LIB_CPP_INC_GUARD
#define  WRAPPED_LIB_CPP_INC_GUARD

#include "lib_cpp.h"

namespace SOME_PROJECT_APPROPRIATE_NAMESPACE
{
  using SOME_WEIRD_NAMESPACE;
}
#endif
```

Some variation of this should work for your situation and the details that you need to maintain are isolated in your wrapping files.